# What does getStaticResourceURL() does in Liferay?

Tags: java, liferay, static-resource

What is the role of the `getStaticResourceURL()` method?

If I pass `request.getContextPath() + mypath` to it (without a timestamp), what it can change? If I pass some timestamp, what it can change additionally?

Comment: You need to provide some more information, e.g. where that method is located etc. Did you read the documentation already?

Comment: Documentation is empty as it usual for Liferay: http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/util/PortalUtil.html#getStaticResourceURL(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, java.lang.String) I found this method in some sample code, it was used to calculate paths of images in portlet JSP; but simple contextpath+mypath also worked for me; so I wonder what does it actualy does and in which circumstances

Answer (score 3):

The method will add a few (undocumented) parameters to the URL:

1. browserId - a friendly name for the browser like "firefox"
2. themeId - the Liferay ThemeId (only for css and jsp files)
3. colorSchemeId - the color scheme id (only for jsp files)
4. minifierType - the minifier type (js or css)
5. languageId - the language id from the Theme
6. b - the Liferay Build Number
7. t - the timestamp for the theme (or the file if it's a /html/* file)

The only place I could find this was in the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.liferay.portal/portal-impl/6.1.0/com/liferay/portal/util/PortalImpl.java)

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/3d5c930c3f8d784099c28e70463cd87a048cb64e/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/util/PortalImpl.java#L5263